# How do I create a list with a range of alphanumerics?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list,

```
['1A11','1A18']
```

How can I create a list using python which uses the above as range and prints the output as:

```
['1A11','1A12','1A13','1A14','1A15','1A16','1A17','1A18']
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use list comprehensions and `.format` method on strings. What did you try so far btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def make_range(pre, r):
    return ['{0}{1}'.format(pre, i) for i in r]

# Example
print (make_range('1A1', range(1, 8)))
# Will print
>>> ['1A11','1A12','1A13','1A14','1A15','1A16','1A17','1A18']
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple list comprehension:

```
l = ['1A11','1A18']
result = [ l[0][:2]+str(i) for i in range(int(l[0][2:]), int(l[1][2:])+1) ]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['1A11', '1A12', '1A13', '1A14', '1A15', '1A16', '1A17', '1A18']
```